# How do I take a value from one function and use it in another?

Tags: python, function, pygame

How do I take the inputted text

```
    screen_text('Zombie Game',75,400,100)
    play_but=screen_but(365,440,280,320)
    play=screen_text('Play',35,400,300)
```

used later using these functions

```
    def text_objects(text,font):
        text_surface = font.render(text,True,RED)
        return text_surface,text_surface.get_rect()
    
    def screen_text(text,size,posx,posy):
        _text = pygame.font.Font('freesansbold.ttf',size)
        text_surf,text_rect = text_objects(text,_text)
        text_rect.center = ((posx),(posy))
        screen.blit(text_surf,text_rect)
```

and use that inputted text, so I can superimpose it to the button

```
    def screen_but(w1,w2,h1,h2):
        while True:
            for ev in pygame.event.get():
                if ev.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                    if w1 <= mouse[0] <= w2 and h1 <= mouse[1] <= h2:
                        return
            mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    
            if w1 <= mouse[0] <= w2 and h1 <= mouse[1] <= h2:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,GREY,[w1,h1,(w2-w1),(h2-h1)])
            else:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,BLACK,[w1,h1,(w2-w1),(h2-h1)])
    
            screen.blit(,(w1+10,h1+10))
            pygame.display.update()
```

Without the screen.blit I can hover over where the rect is and the highlighting of the button works, however I just can't seem to find a way to allow the text to be superimposed onto it without taking it out of the functions. But I want to be able to use it more than just the once in my program.

Comment: I can't figure out what value you want to be available in what function, but the general answer is to have it take that value as a parameter.  If a function generates a value you want to use elsewhere, have it `return` the value so the caller can reuse it.

Comment: I'm confused.  Nothing in there is inputting any text at all.  That's all just displaying constant text strings.

Comment: The text that I input into screen_text 'Zombie Game', I want to be able to take that out of screen_text and use it in screen_but, in the screen.blit. Because I can't just enter screen_text as it doesn't allow functions to be used in .blit

Comment: I have no idea what you question is about. A function can `return` a value (or tuple, list, object ...). `screen_text` doesn't return anything. Are you searching for `return text_surf`?

Comment: If I return the values of screen_text and place it inside the screen.blit in screen_but, it comes back saying 'TypeError: argument 1 must be pygame.Surface, not function'

Comment: Please learn the basics. In the last line of `screen_text()` do `return text_surf`. Call `play = screen_text('Play',35,400,300)`. Later you can use `play`, e.g. `screen.blit(play,(w1+10,h1+10))`

Comment: Thanks, that has solved it and sorry for the misunderstanding. I probably should have learnt the basics, yes. But I usually learn as I do projects, as I find it easier to learn and remember.

Answer (score 0):

Return the *Sprite* from the function:

```py
def screen_text(text,size,posx,posy):
    # [...]

    return text_surf
```

Call the function and store the return value in a variable (`play`):

```py
play = screen_text('Play',35,400,300)
```

Later you can use the `play` variable.  e.g.:

```py
screen.blit(play, (w1+10, h1+10))
```